# In App Purchase currency update

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, currency, in-app-billing

I'm having a problem. When I put up an in app purchase item (lets call it item_x) I set the USD price at 1.99

Now my major problem is that since I sell in several countries  (those that have iap allowed) I would like their currency price to stay the same (e.g. $1.99 regardless of what currency they are using) So far I have to press auto-convert prices each day to keep it relatively stable. Is there any way to force google to auto calculate other counties prices based on current price??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do this.

Sometimes your USD price, when converted to the price in another country, may not match the minimum pricing required for an item in a particular country. Due to this, completely automated pricing is not possible, and you have to do at least some of it manually.